# how to use value that is calculated inside ssh

Tags: linux, shell

I have linux script like below:

```
sshpass -p "pwd" ssh -tt user << 'EOF'  
cd /directory  
file=$(ls -1t | head -1)  
exit  
EOF
```

How to use the file parameter outside ssh. That is after `EOF` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to work with the output of the SSH command to capture it into a local variable.

This could be a viable solution (tried with obviously different parameters locally, OS Ubuntu 17.04):

```
CMD=`cat <<EOF
cd /directory
ls -1t | head -1
EOF`

FILE=`sshpass -p "pass" ssh -t user@host -o LogLevel=QUIET "$CMD"`
echo "$FILE"
```

Comment: But I have multiple commands to execute inside ssh. So I have to use EOF. I tried this alternative but its not working with EOF.